# Is it possible to overwrite an html file (folium map) and display it on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, folium

Is it possible to overwrite an html file and display it on Heroku? If so, will other people that use the site see the overwritten HTML site? What I want to do is overwrite an html map file with a selected folium map and include that in the index.html with jinja when the page is reloaded. I know this will work locally, however how can I do this with Heroku and have the folium map overwrites only occur for one user locally. Should I be doing this a different way?

Thanks, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Vaguely speaking, somewhere in your app that you are deploying on Heroku you are going to have an endpoint that involves something like:

```
@api.route('/folium_maps/<int:map_id>')
```

where map_id is the integer that corresponds to one of the folium maps you wish to display, i.e. you have 5 different possible maps and you arbitrarily give each one a unique identifier, such as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Your endpoint should return an html file that includes the map that was selected, which should be easy to accomplish using jinja templating.

Put your Flask/Django app on Heroku and now other people will be able to see the overwritten HTML site.

Because of the nature of how jinja works, user selection of which map to display will occur for only that user locally.

Comment: Hi @Matthew Skillman. Thanks for the response. I actually want to show the map locally, but im not sure whether overwriting the map will result in it being changed in the actual github/heroku file and whether other people will see it when one user submits parameters and the map is overwritten. If a user does something that triggers a map.save on an already existing map on my heroku server, will it result in that change only being shown locally, or will other people experience the overwrite? Thanks Matthew.

Comment: @PaulMcBurney Hi, either behaviors that you mentioned- changes being shown only locally, or, other people experiencing the overwrite, are possible, depending on how your backend is configured. Given that your map objects exist on your server, not within the client’s web browser, I would imagine that any edits to map objects will reflect on all clients, upon refresh of the browser. Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok. @Matthew Skillman, do you have any advice on how I could complete this problem? Here is an example (not what im actually doing). So say that I wanted to place a marker on the map on a longitude and latitude that the user inputs in the HTML file. Say I want this to occur for only that user and then when that user refreshes the page the map is completely reset and the marker is gone. I want to avoid saving the folium map in an HTML file. How would one complete this task? Would it be possible to render a map with Jinja instead of saving the folium map? Thanks.

Comment: @PaulMcBurney In short, I don’t think I will be able to provide a good answer to you. I’m fairly knowledgeable about jinja and deploying apps to cloud service providers, but I do not have enough experience with Folium to intuit what the solution here is. I would venture to say that you should write some Javascript that allows for a marker to be placed at a particular pair of coordinates within the Folium map within the webpage.